# PHPmyAdmin Hebrew Collation

Tags: encoding, phpmyadmin

My project uses Windows-1255 encoding.
The website works fine.
But after upgrading phpMyAdmin on local machine I can't see hebrew characters in phpMyAdmin.
The table's collation is latin_swedish_ci. Same is database and phpMyAdmin.
This is how it looks now: ֳ·ֳ¸ֳ¡ ֳ´ֳ¥ֳ°ֳ¢

Anybody had this problem?

Ubuntu 10.04, phpMyAdminVersion information: 3.4.10.1deb1